# Trying to understand the expected behaviour in a static_cast

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand some details of `static_cast`.

Please have a look at the following code,

```cpp
struct A
{
    int data = 0;
};

void foo(const A* a)
{
    (*static_cast<A**>(static_cast<void*>(&a)))->data = 1;
}

void bar(const A* a)
{
    const_cast<A*>(a)->data = 1;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    foo(&a);
    return a.data;
}
```

Is the function `foo` valid C++ code?
Is there any valid usage that gives a different result with `foo` vs. `bar`?

Comment: The cast in `bar` is a NOP anyway if I'm not too tired.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I cast away constness to write to data.

Comment: See, I was tired and missed the const. I assume `foo` compiles? Interesting.

Comment: I used `-std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Werror` with `clang 9.0.0` and the whole thing compiles (even with `bar` instead of `foo`).

Comment: This is undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing rule violation (you alias `const A *` as `A *`)

Comment: @M.M There is an exception for types that are [*similar*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#lval-8.3). Does that not apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions are valid C++ and have well-defined behavior (modifying the `data` member of the `A` object created in `main`) in C++11 and later.

You are allowed to obtain a pointer to non-`const` from a pointer to `const` object type either directly with `const_cast` or indirectly with `static_cast` going through `void*` as you are doing in `foo`. That in itself is not a problem:

The cast to `void*` is possible because `&a` is a pointer to `const A*` which is not (top-level) cv-qualified. The cast from `void*` to `A**` is possible because `void*` can be cast to any object pointer type. Dereferencing the result is accessing the `const A*` object through a pointer to `A*`, but that [is ok](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#lval-8.3) because the types are [*similar*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.qual#def:similar_types). (The last part [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/11941443) to have been an aliasing rule violation prior to C++11, making this undefined behavior.)

However, modifying a `const` qualified object through a pointer to non-`const` obtained in such a way causes undefined behavior.

Since the object `A a;` that you are passing to the function is not `const` qualified, there is no problem.

But I think it is obvious why using such functions is dangerous. Changing the declaration `A a;` to `const A a;` will still compile because there is no type mismatch, but will have undefined behavior.

Both functions do exactly the same thing in all situations, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now `const_cast` seems a bit redundant to me. Maybe there are use-cases I can't see.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect The intent of `const_cast` is to explicitly state what is happening, because as I mentioned in my answer, using it is always dangerous and requires special care to be taken. If you are talking strictly about redundance, then `((A*)a)->data = 1;` would also do it and C style cast allows most other casts as well.